# Need to hide “Ship to this Address” box if not allowed in billing : Magento

Tags: magento, billing

I am stuck with a problem, where I need to hide the radio box “Ship to this Address” at the bottom of the billing information, only when a customer selects a specific country. Any idea on how to approach ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to sound sarcastic, I'd do the following:

- Listen for the `onchange` event from the billing country dropdown
- Hide the tick box if the dropdown has an appropriate value

There doesn't need to be anything Magento specific about this, be pragmatic and approach it from a standard web development point of view.